# Link generator JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to generate an HTML Link using JavaScript,

Here's the Code.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function lab() {      
          var myTextField = document.getElementById('redir');
          var texto = myTextField.value;
          url = "<a target='_blank' href='" + texto + "'>Click</a> Para continuar.";
          document.getElementById("red").innerHTML = url;
</script>     

<form name="test" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
Web: <input type="text" id ="redir" name="redir"><br>
<input type="button" onClick="lab()" value="Generate code" >

<b id="red" >Link</b>
```

The problem is... When i click the generated link doesnt work well, just take me to the localhost/ and i want to go out....

Comment: Thank you, i already updat! (0;

Comment: Step through the code and find out what `myTextField.value` is. If the value is empty, your link will be faulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) use onsubmit and return false
2) test the field is not empty
3) only use type=url if you insist the redir must be something like `http://aaa.bbb.ccc`

If you want to allow the user to type `google.com` you need to NOT use `type="url"` but then you MUST test if there is http:// in front and if not, add it, otherwise it will go to a relative url based on the page with the form

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/uZrLR/)

```
<script>
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("test").onsubmit=function() {
    var texto = this.redir.value;
    if (texto) {
      // next line only needed for non-html5 aware browsers or type="text"
      if (texto.indexOf('http://')!=0) texto = 'http://'+texto;
      document.getElementById("red").innerHTML = "<a target='_blank' href='" + texto + "'>Click</a> Para continuar.";
    }
    return false;
  }
}
</script>     

<form id="test">
Web: <input type="url" id="redir" name="redir"/><br />
<input type="submit" value="Generate code"/>
</form>
<b id="red" >Link</b>
```

Comment: Yeah Thank you!, actually this code works perfect, but, the problem is the link doesn't take me out, showms me something like http://localhost/test/linkeout/crypt/goog.com on the localhost!... so what i need is this link taken me out to the website!, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

change `<input type="text" id ="redir" name="redir">` to `<input type="url" id ="redir" name="redir">` so that the browser ensures only URLs are being submitted.
Then modify:

```
 function lab() {      
        var myTextField = document.getElementById('redir');
        var texto = myTextField.value;
        url = "<a target='_blank' href='" + texto + "'>Click</a> Para continuar.";
        document.getElementById("red").innerHTML = url;
    }
```

to:

```
function lab() {      
    var myTextField = document.getElementById('redir');
    var texto = myTextField.value;
    if(texto != '')
    {
        url = "<a target='_blank' href='" + texto + "'>Click</a> Para continuar.";
        document.getElementById("red").innerHTML = url;
    } else {
        alert(' please enter a valid url');
    }
}
```

Comment: Type=url is not going to do anything on its own and then only in HTML5 aware browsers

Comment: Yeah Thank you!, but, the problem is the link doesn't take me out, showms me something like http://localhost/test/linkeout/crypt/goog.com on the localhost!... so what i need is this link taken me out to the website!, Thank you!